# can anti-proxy settings be used with dynamic proxys?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

I'm using tor to get round a restrictive proxy, but the IP of the proxy rotates and changes depending on what computer I'm using. Can I put in a range of IPs and have tor route through them?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell what you're trying to do from the above post; do you mean that you want to route Tor through the proxy in question, or is the proxy transparent to you (just sitting between you and the internet) and you just want to use Tor to byepass it (in which case you shouldn't have to do anything)?

Comment: @SamWhited Both in a way. It doesn't work when I try to connect without the proxy, so I presume that must be the problem. Aaaaand I think it may block https but I'm not sure -- sometimes https sites work, sometimes they don't.